# Align text inside div using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

[image]

How to align the two parts of equation in a single line. Please look the picture given, Both parts are inside a div.
The HTML structure is like this..

```
<div>
  <table>
    //the first part here(red circle)
  </table>
  second part here(blue circle)
</div>
```

I can only access the div. Rest of them are dynamically created. So by providing a style to div how can I align the both parts in a single line.

I can't change the structure.

This alignment issue is only occurs in TinyMCE editor. When i print the equation in normal div, this is aligned properly.

Please give me a solution using CSS or tinyMCE feature which is really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the alignment? How should it be? What is the exact HTML output? The general HTML structure in this case really does not help at all. If the alignment is the only issue, why can't you use `text-align`?

Comment: Tables for laying out text is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the display property to inline-block to show them in a single line just like this:

```
<html>
    <div>
      <table>
        the first part here(red circle)
      </table>
      second part here(blue circle)
    </div>

    <style>
          div { display:inline-block; }
           table{display:inline-block;}
          /* for IE6-7 */
          @media,
              {
                  div { display: inline; margin-right:10px; }
              }
    </style>
</html>
```

take a look at this [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/fLfvLg3q/1/)

Comment: i can't put style or format the table. I can  access the div only.So i need to style div only.